# PHP Online refund in Firstdata payment gateway (Payeezy)

Tags: magento2, php, api, payment-methods

I have implemented the Firstdata payment gateway for online payment. It is working fine. Now I want to implement the online refund functionality. If anyone provide me the sample script for Firstdata payment gateway in PHP then bit thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For online refund first of all you need to place the order after order placing success Firstdata payment gateway return the response with success or error. In success response you need to use the real "transaction_tag", "authorization_num" values at refund time. You can see the below working script just you need to configure it by your merchant account credentials.

I hope it will work.

```
$host = "api.demo.globalgatewaye4.firstdata.com";
$protocol = "https://";
$uri = "/transaction/v12";
$hmackey = "HMAC key";
$keyid = "Key ID";
$gatewayid = "Gateway ID";
$password = "Password";

$location = $protocol . $host . $uri;
$request = array(
'transaction_type' => "34", //for refund
'amount' => "60.50", // refundable amount
'transaction_tag' => "Transaction Tag No.", //order place time respond by Payeezy
'authorization_num' => "Authorization No.", //order place time respond by Payeezy
'gateway_id' => $gatewayid,
'password' => $password,
);
$content = json_encode($request);

$gge4Date = strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", time()) . 'Z';
$contentType = "application/json";
$contentDigest = sha1($content);
$method = "POST";

$hashstr = "$method\n$contentType\n$contentDigest\n$gge4Date\n$uri";
$authstr = 'GGE4_API ' . $keyid . ':' . base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha1", $hashstr, $hmackey, true));

$headers = array( 
    "Content-Type: $contentType",
    "X-GGe4-Content-SHA1: $contentDigest",
    "X-GGe4-Date: $gge4Date",
    "Authorization: $authstr",
    "Accept: $contentType"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $location);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($output);
```

Comment: I have used your sample code with my credentials. It is showing authentication error

Comment: Which type merchant account you are using live or demo environment? Actually above script for demo environment. If you are using live account then just you need to remove the "demo." from host. Then it will work

Comment: Yes, I am using the merchant demo account and added merchant demo account credentials still showing the authentication error

Comment: Which Encryption Type you are using at order placing time? There are two types encryptions SHA1 and MD5. I have encrypted by "SHA1" and I did enabled it in merchant account > Payment Pages > Security and then check the Encryption Type = "HMAC-SHA1" and click on save changes button.

Comment: Ah! there was encryption key problem. Just I have configured it in merchant account as per given your steps and using the SHA1. Now it is working fine. Thank you so much...